# skip a command in powershell

Tags: powershell, curl

I have 20 `curl` commands in powershell. I created a loop to run them continually. When a command responses too long maybe it is error, i want to skip it to the others commands continue.

```
$i = 1
while($true){
write-Progress -activity  "SCAN"  -status  "ROUND       $i"
write-host "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ROUND $i +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" -foregroundcolor "red" -backgroundcolor "white"
curl 10.0.119.61:8101
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.61:8101<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.61:8101
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.61:8102<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.61:8102
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.62:8201<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.62:8201
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.62:8202<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.62:8202
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.63:8301<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow" 
curl 10.0.119.63:8301
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.63:8302<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.63:8302
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.64:8401<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.64:8401
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.64:8402<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.64:8402
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.65:8501<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.65:8501
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.65:8502<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.65:8502
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.66:8601<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.66:8601
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.66:8602<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.66:8602
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.67:8701<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.67:8701
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.67:8702<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.67:8702
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.68:8801<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.68:8801
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.68:8802<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.68:8802
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.69:8901<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.69:8901
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.69:8902<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.69:8902
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.70:9001<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.70:9001
write-host =============================>>10.0.119.70:9002<<============================= -foregroundcolor "darkgreen" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
curl 10.0.119.70:9002
sleep 5
$i++
if ($i % 10 -eq 0){
clear
$i++
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by `curl` you mean the default aliased **`Invoke-Webrequest`**, then use **`-TimeoutSec`**

From [Powershell Docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1)

> **-TimeoutSec** 
>       Specifies how long the request can be pending before it times out.
>  
>       Enter a value in seconds. The default value, 0, specifies
>   an indefinite time-out.

i.e:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -TimeoutSec 30 "http://address.com/"
```

Would set a 30 second timeout

---

**Sidenote** to do this in actual `cURL`:
`--connect-timeout` <seconds>